# Problems passing and using selectors when making buttons

Tags: objective-c, callback, selector, nsbutton

I am trying to do some coding in Xcode and am having some problems with selectors.  I have created a subclass of `NSButton` called `modifiedNSButton`.  One of the constructors is

```
+ (id)CreateButtonViewUsingObject:(id)targetObject  selector:(SEL)select caption:(NSString *)label;
```

However, the only way I have been able to get it to work is to pass the selector as `@selector(bleep:)`  It works but I get the message

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'SEL'

I assume that this means that `@selector(bleep:)` is sent as an `NSString` instead of a `SEL`. However, it seems to work and I can't tell if I am doing something wrong.  I will post my code to my Git for people to look at and then give a pointer to the location.

Comment: Post a [mre] in the question please.

Comment: Does `CreateButtonViewUsingObject:selector:caption:` do the same as `buttonWithTitle:target:action:`?

Answer (score 0):

First, you really should  follow the naming conventions in Objective C:

- your Class should be named `ModifiedNSButton`, starting with a big letter
- in contrary, functions should start with a small letter

Then, a "constructor" should also follow some conventions:

- The return type should be `instancetype`, not `id`
- If it's an initializer, start with `init...` (like `initUsingObject...`)
- If it's a class factory, start the function with the name of the class.

In your case, you should name it
`+ (instancetype) modifiedNSButtonUsingObject:(id)targetObject selector:(SEL)select caption:(NSString*)label`

After all this said, I don't see a problem with your code:

```
@interface ModifiedNSButton : NSButton

@end

@implementation ModifiedNSButton

+ (instancetype)modifiedNSButtonUsingObject:(id)targetObject selector:(SEL)select caption:(NSString *)label {
    return [self new];
}

- (void) handler {
}

- (void) handlerWithName:(NSString*)name andValue:(NSInteger)value {
}

- (void) test {
    NSButton *b1 = [ModifiedNSButton modifiedNSButtonUsingObject:self selector:@selector(handler) caption:@"One"];
    NSButton *b2 = [ModifiedNSButton modifiedNSButtonUsingObject:self selector:@selector(handlerWithName:andValue:) caption:@"Two"];
}
@end
```

I don't see any "incompatible pointer type" warnings.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  It seems like there have been changes in the language due to things like ARC and some of my documents I am using for coding seem to use syntax from different years.  I am going to redo the code following your suggestions.  Just one point of confusion left at the moment.  Why do you have nil for the object receiving the messages from the button?  Is nil appropriate if it is for the same object. (instead of self)  Frankly, it seems that manuals have been dropping in quality and clarity since IBM/370 and VAX/VMS.

Comment: Regarding `nil` -- it's just some sample code, better should be `self`. I'll change this.

Comment: Can `NSButton` handle a `handler` or `handlerWithName:andValue:` action? Shouldn't the action be an [action message](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Target-Action/Target-Action.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH12-SW32)?

Comment: Many more thanks to Andreas Oetjen on your assistance.  I went through your example and compared it to various locations in my code and now the pieces I have written are working fine.